# How to find Table and append a new record to its Store?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I need to update a Store based on some information that I have.

I have a table in the document, that uses some Store to keep data, 
and in separate part of page I have a button that needs to add some information to the Store (and table). I got a bit confused, so, I just ask here all I need to know:

1. Which property in table configuration needs to be specified to locate table later?
2. Which call I need to make to find the table and locate its store?
3. How I can generate and append data to the table's existing store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "table" you are referring to is [Grid](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel) in ExtJS terminology.

1. To get the grid for later use, you need a reference to that object. There are many ways in ExtJS to get hold of this reference.

**Using Javascript Variables**: Most simple way is to have a javascript variable that will hold the reference. This is usually done when the grid is created. For example:

```
var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    // All the configs...
});
```

You can use the `myGrid` variable to get access to the grid.

**Using ComponentManager**: When an ExtJS component is created, it gets registered with the component manager. You can always get hold of an ExtJS component from this register. The manager tracks each component with a unique id. To use this method, you will have to define a unique id for your grid component and later use the famous `Ext.getCmp()` method. Here is an example:

```
var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        id: 'myGrid',   // Unique id for the grid
    // All other configs...
});
```

Using this method is NOT the best practice.

**Using itemId and Component Query**: A better method than the above two; you can use the `itemId` config and [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery). ComponentQuery class provides a selector-based searching for Sencha Components analogous to DOM querying. Example:

```
var myGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        itemId: 'myGrid',   
    // All other configs...
});
```

And to get a reference, you may call the `query()` method from a container or use Ext.ComponentManager (this is global).

**Accessing in MVC controller**: If you are developing your application using MVC, you can make use of this method. A controller have reference array namely: `refs`. (Internally, the method makes use of ComponentQuery and selectors to access the component). Refer MVC guides and examples to see how this works..

---

2. Once you obtain the grid with any the above techniques, you can get the store simply by calling the method: `getStore()`. This returns the store object (`Ext.data.Store`). Example:

```
myStore = myGrid.getStore();
```

---

3. Refer the [Ext.data.Store](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store) documentation. you can manipulate your grid's store using methods like `add()`,`load()`,`remove()` etc...

Answer (score 1):

FYI.
It is not

```
Ext.Cmp()
```

it is

```
Ext.getCmp('myGrid')
```